# android cursor in infinite loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I have cursor that comes from a cursor loader. The problem is if I try to move through that cursor it  will not move foward and puts in a endless loop.

```
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, final Cursor cursor) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CALLED onLoadFinished");
    ...
    else if(loader.getId() == LOADER_1)
    {
        while(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
              Log.d(TAG, "LOOPING");
              cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Good thinking let me see

Comment: I removed all uses of cursor and just left the plain loop, but still stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `while` loop will not work. Right now you're moving the cursor to the first position in the `while` condition then inside the`while` block you're pushing the cursor to the next position. As the `while` block is finished the condition will be tested again so `cursor.moveToFirst()` will be called again. This will continue again and again. Basically you'll move from the first position to the second position of the cursor in an infinite loop.

The loop should be like this:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
     Log.d(TAG, "LOOPING");
     // do other stuff 
     // each time you'll have a new row from the cursor
}
```

Comment: This is how I did it `while ((currentLine != null) || (lineFirstIteration)) ` It worked for a long time but when my dodgy code caused an infinite loop, I converted to your correct method and it has worked flawlessly